# match class with regex for a custom validation rule

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validator for validation. I am trying to add a custom rule for class. Here I am wanting to match the class using a regex. But it's not working.

Sample:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "cMin",
    $.validator.methods.min,
    "* lower than min value"
);

jQuery.validator.addClassRules('(min\[)\d+(\.\d+)?\]', { // here I am trying to check the class name with regex
    cMin: 10
});
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your regular expression doing way, But use the `jquery each`,

Demo [JSFIDDLE Particular class validation](http://jsfiddle.net/GrhBr/202/)

Try this,

```
$('input').each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("class") == "test"){ // here try to check the class name with regex
jQuery.validator.addClassRules($(this).attr("class"),{

            required: true,
            maxlength: 10
        });
    }
});
```

I hope this will help you..

Comment: -1 for using a `submit()` handler in your demo.  Perhaps you don't realize that this plugin has a perfectly good set of [callback functions](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) built into it.  There's also no need to put a conditional check inside your `.each()` when you could simply target the appropriate class in the first place.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/mDRpN/1/

Comment: `addClassRules` is for creating compound rules that can be applied by class names.  Since you're targeting all fields with `.test` by wrapping it inside an `.each()`, you might as well just use the `.rules('add')` method.  http://jsfiddle.net/mDRpN/2/

Comment: @Sparky I am not much familiar with validation plugin. But **raisul** question is match the class with regex, If matched that class should be validate. Please see this link http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/GrhBr/203/

Comment: That has nothing to do with your blatant misuse of `.each()`.

Comment: @Sparky ok can you explain me how to do this with regex, Because I am using this way in my programming career. I hope you give the better solution for me.

Comment: You don't need regex, and I gave you two better solutions in my first two comments if you'd only take a minute to look at them.